# Use content of text file as a source to develop code

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

[image]

I will like to develop a process in which a string in a text file could be used as a source when writing code for replacing other values/strings. In other words I will like not to manually type in the strings (example- rainfall) to replace in code, but rather it be read from a text file. (See Picture examples)

I assume an array or list is needed here.

Comment: You may want to check out [CookieCutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For anyone who has a similar request. This is how i solved the issue.with open(r'C:\temp\game_title\Game Title.txt','r') as file:
    text = " ".join(line.rstrip() for line in file)
    print(text)
substring = text